# How to loop through nodes for a specific label and show how many distinct nodes connect to it (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I am using neo4j as my db. I want to do this thing in neo4j browser: given a label (e.g. Case), find out for every node that belongs to this label, how many distinct node(belongs to the other Label) connect it.

I was trying this:

```
MATCH (e1:Event) - [hc1:HAS_CASE] -> (c:Case) <- [hc2 :HAS_CASE] - (e2:Event) WHERE e1.eventId <> e2.eventId RETURN c
```

to list all the c that has two distinct nodes connecting to it.

But every time I ran this, neo4j browser crashed. I am thinking this query might be very memory and time consuming. So what should it do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` to find the number of distinct `Event` nodes that have a `HAS_CASE` relationship directed at each `Case` node.

For example:

```
MATCH (c:Case)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:HAS_CASE]-(e:Event)
RETURN c, COUNT(DISTINCT e);
```

The second `MATCH` is `OPTIONAL` so that you will still get a result for  `Case` nodes that have no associated events.

*NOTE: The `DISTINCT` option is only needed if it is possible for a `Case` node to have multiple `HAS_CASE` relationships with the same `Event` node instance.*